# Capybara throwing random Capybara::Poltergeist::DeadClient: errors

Tags: rspec, capybara

When running feature tests that use Capybara together, either as running the whole suite or by just running 2 spec files together via `rspec` I'm getting intermittent errors:

```
 Capybara::Poltergeist::DeadClient:
   PhantomJS client died while processing
```

While trying to get to fix these it's gone some times with it not happening for a dozen or so runs to every run.

I've tried the following:

```
# .rspec
--order rand

# capybara config
Capybara.register_driver :custom do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app,
    # setting js_errors to true or false makes no difference
    js_errors: false, 
    timeout: 180
  )
)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after(:each, :js) do
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end
end
```

I've also tried rspec-retry but that didn't seem to help at all.

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest PhantomJS (2.1.1 currently - with a 2.5 beta available as well) and make sure you have enough free memory.

Comment: I do have 2.1.1 (latest version available via homebrew) and 6GB of memory free when running the specs.

Comment: Really the only other thing you can do is to use the url_whitelist/blacklist settings to block any unneeded resources that are being loaded -- unfortunately PhantomJS hasn't been updated in quite some time and has some stability issues.  Hopefully that is going to improve when 2.5 is released.